# How to download and install Utorrent for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: downloads, utorrent

I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to this. I downloaded the .tar.gz file from the Utorrent website and extracted it to a folder I made in the Home directory. I tried executing the executable file but nothing seemed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **change the permissions** of the executable file.

Suppose you extracted .tar.gz to a directory *utorrent* in *home* directory and the executable file is named as *utorrent-1.0* and it is in *utorrent* directory.

You will have to execute following set of commands for executing utorrent-1.0

Open terminal (Crtl+Alt+T) and execute following commands.

```
chmod +x ~/utorrent/utorrent-1.0
```

The above command will add executable attribute on utorrent-1.0 file

```
cd ~/utorrent && ./utorrent-1.0
```

The above command will execute utorrent-1.0

The example is arbitrary, replace *utorrent* with name (or path) of directory where you extracted files and replace *utorrent-1.0* with executable file located in the said directory.